# How do I convert spaced columns to tabs?

Tags: linux, sed, tabs, format, tabular

> This question is not a duplicate as someone had suggested. Mods, pay attention

I'm running a for loop on multiple files that contain information like below

```
1    Leer            Normal   [status]     —      100
1    Wrap            Normal   [physical]   15     90
4    Poison Sting    Poison   [physical]   15     100
9    Bite            Dark     [physical]   60     100
12   Glare           Normal   [status]     —      100
17   Screech         Normal   [status]     —      85
20   Acid            Poison   [special]    40     100
25   Spit Up         Normal   [special]    —      100
25   Stockpile       Normal   [status]     —      —
25   Swallow         Normal   [status]     —      —
28   Acid Spray      Poison   [special]    40     100
33   Mud Bomb        Ground   [special]    65     85
36   Gastro Acid     Poison   [status]     —      100
38   Belch           Poison   [special]    120    90
41   Haze            Ice      [status]     —      —
44   Coil            Poison   [status]     —      —
49   Gunk Shot       Poison   [physical]   120    80
```

I need to be able to extract data from it.

The problem is, each file has different column lengths.

---

Column 2 sometimes has spaces in it so squeezing all spaces and using space as a delimiter for cut is not an option. I need the columns separated by tabs without using specific information because the loop goes over about 800 files.

```
sed 's/  \+/ /g' | cut -f 2 -d " "
```

^ Not what I need since column 2 has spaces in it

```
cut -b "5-20"
```

^ Can't use this either because the columns lengths are different for each file.

Answer (score 1):

With sed, to replace multiples consecutive spaces or tabs with one tab:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]\{1,\}/\t/g' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `s`: substitute
- `[[:space:]]`: space or tab characters
- `\{1,\}`: when at least one occurrence is found
- `g`: apply substitution to all occurrences in line

**Edit**:

To preserve single spaces in second column, you can replace only when 2 spaces/tabs are found:

```
    sed 's/[[:space:]]\{2,\}/\t/g' file
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. If someone could explain this code to me also that would be great.

Comment: Looking bat at it, it does exactly what I didn't need it to do. It also converted the spaces in the 2nd column to tabs. I provided example scripts that do exactly what you said but much simpler to show what will not work.

Comment: You're right. I edited and added some explanations.